# Failed to initialize storage: failed to perform migrations: creating migration table: unable to open database file

Tags: django, sqlite, amazon-ec2, openid-dex

I am building a django application and also using dex for Token Authentication. This application is deployed on AWS EC2 but when I run the dex file it gives an error .

I am using sqlite3 as a database for dex .

This is my dex file
[image]

This is the error
[image]

Any help will means a lot. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error and when googling it I find your question. I successfully  run dex after chmod the directory where my sqlite database was located.

The SQLite documentation tells that if you want that an app does a RW in the database, your app should be allow to write in the directory.

So chmod -R 660 data is the anwser.

Y.